# getting previous 6 months getting issue

Tags: php

I am facing issue to get last 6 months in the basis of month number

```
    $vBillMonthPrev = '11';

        for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
            $m_array[] = date("M-y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $vBillMonthPrev - $i, 15));
        }

foreach ($m_array as $months) {
           echo  $months;
        }
```

issue is this the above code return Oct-21Sep-21Aug-21Jul-21Jun-21May-21
and required result should be Oct-20 Sep-20 Aug-20 Jul-20 Jun-20 May-20

Comment: because it's required to print previous month billing history with months and year

Comment: @JohnConde this is the requirements to print previous months history on a consumer bil

Comment: But it's 2021 now, so how is `mktime` to know you mean 2020?

Comment: you are right but this is the requirements to print previous 6 months history on consumer bill, for example if current month is November 2020 on bill, previous months history will be displayed on a bill like Oct-20 Sep-20 Aug-20 Jul-20 Jun-20 May-20, but it's displayed 2021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to deal with your year issue is to compare `$vBillMonthPrev` with the current month, and if it is greater than that, supplying a `year` parameter to `mktime` which is for the previous year. Then you can make a `DateTime` object from that date, and subtract one month in a loop to generate values into your `$m_array`. Note that it is preferable to subtract a month at a time rather than making a new date variable, as this will correctly deal with the case where the month underflows into the previous year.

```php
$vBillMonthPrev = '11';
$vBillYearPrev = (int)date('Y') - ((int)$vBillMonthPrev > (int)date('n') ? 1 : 0);

$date = date_create_from_format('U', mktime(0, 0, 0, $vBillMonthPrev, 15, $vBillYearPrev));

$m_array = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $date->modify('-1 month');
    $m_array[] = $date->format('M-y');
}

print_r($m_array);
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Oct-20
    [1] => Sep-20
    [2] => Aug-20
    [3] => Jul-20
    [4] => Jun-20
    [5] => May-20
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FST4C)

Answer (score 0):

just add a year parameter just like that

```
<?php
    $vBillMonthPrev = '11';
    for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $m_array[] = date("M-y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $vBillMonthPrev - $i, 15, 2020));
    }

   foreach ($m_array as $months) {
       echo  $months;
    }
?>
```